# How to create a leaderboard that sorts by score and time mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to implement a leaderboard which acts like a queue instead of a score board i.e.

```
user  score  time position
1     1      1    1
2     1      2    2
3     0      1    3
4     0      2    4
```

My question is how one should structure a query to derive a user's position in this queue considering the fact that the time is also taken into account, the following depicts a function that derives the user position from the collection:

```
public async position(leaderboardId: string, id: any) {
        const user = await this.get(leaderboardId, id);
        return await this.getCollection(leaderboardId).
            find({
                score: {
                    $gt: user.score
                }
            }).
            count() + 1;
    }
```

However, if multiple users have the same score, it will mean a draw for all users with that score (position) i.e.

```
user  score  time position
1     1      1    1
2     1      2    1
3     0      1    3
4     0      2    3
```

How does one modify the aforementioned query to implement the respective logic?
Thanks